# Too much draining of battery at night

Tags: custom-roms, battery-life

I have Samsung Galaxy core gti8262 rooted.
And smoothly running on custom rom. I am having the battery issue in night my phones battery drains suddenly from 80% to 40-35%.I don't know why is this happening only at night,never happened this in day time!
Anyone tell me about this why is this occurring???

Comment: can you check battery logs in system settings? use an app called "GSam battery monitor" from play store. it will give you good details of which app is using your battery and how much.

Comment: Probably because of Google back up happening? It happens late night / early morning when phone is idle and connected WiFI. Disconnect WiFi to confirm if the drain is due to this